# Как проверить есть ли символ в JTextArea? JAVA

Tags: java, swing, awt

Есть поле JTextArea, нужно сделать так что-бы программа проверяла есть ли символы и выполняла какие то действия.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно достать текст методом getText() и проверить его на содержание текста

```
JTextArea jTextArea = new JTextArea();
String text = jTextArea.getText();
if(text.equals("")){
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]